# SMILES vs. Graph for generating molecules

Tags: cheminformatics, machine-learning

I have seen [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/128149/smiles-vs-graph-representation-in-deep-learning?newreg=475762532b0b4b7c96489aaa1c4c7677), but mine is slightly different, focusing on *generating* molecules.

There are many published methods for generating molecules; some of which generate SMILES and others directly generate graphs. Comparing these two approaches, I came to the following conclusions:

- These two structures can be converted to each other. Obviously, we can obtaion SMILES from graphs by graph traversal. On the other hand, one can generate graph from SMILES using `MolFromSmiles` function in rdkit. One can say that the graph representation may contain more information represented in their nodes/edges feature vectors, but I assume that current generators just generate graph structures.
- The main merit of directly generating graphs over SMILES is that we hope that the former generates better molecules. This is because, as mentioned in [MolGAN paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11973), models that generate SMILES have to spend capacity on learning both the syntactic rules and the order ambiguity of the representation.

I appreciate if you can "validate" or "correct" the above conclusions.

Comment: Yes, I would prefer using a graph as it's easier to validate.
Also, if I were you I would take a look at SELFIES, which were made exactly to generate valid molecules.
https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.13741v1

Comment: I don't understand the machine learning aspect, but a graph (whether 3d or 2d) could theoretically encode (a lot) more information than smiles. Therefore, I'd conclude that you cannot convert smiles to graph without assumptions/prerequisites, which makes your point 1 wrong. For your second point, I'm missing what a better molecule would be. The inherent ambiguity of smiles is always going to be problematic. I guess in general, thus question would probably gain better suited responses on the more technical oriented site [mattermodeling.se].

Comment: @Martin-マーチン - SMILES encodes a molecular bond graph. So all SMILES can be encoded as that graph. While the syntax is ambiguous, there is the DeepSMILES variant (and SELFIES). Regardless, for both graphs and string representations, the order is ambiguous. That can be a good thing, since you can randomize atom order to augment your data set.

Comment: I'd agree with @Martin-マーチン that I don't know what "better" means. I can imagine invalid molecular graphs (e.g., 6 bonds to a carbon) as much as invalid SMILES. That's continued to be a problem with generative ML methods - much like generative image ML can produce really weird faces, animals, etc.